# Trying to debug .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am getting started with the mod_rewrite function for my PHP webpage

I was superexcited to have created my first rewrite rule, but when I added to my .htaccess file, I got error 500 for all webpages (not only the one I am trying to redirect).

Here is my file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]*)/(([^/]*)/)*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.htm !-f
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)\/([0-9]+)$ ficha_jugador.php?idjugador=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
```

My new line is 8th, the rest came by default in my webserver

I tried something much easier for line 8th just to test

```
RewriteRule ^writetest\.html http://www.after5pc.net [QSA,L]
```

But it also ended up in 500 error, so it does not seem a syntax problem

Eventually, what I want to do is to change (slug my URLs)

```
http://cadistas1910.com/ficha_jugador.php?idjugador=1304
by
http://cadistas1910.com/alvaro-garcia-canto/alvaro-garcia/1304
```

Any help you guys can provide? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe last line of your .htaccess file could be the culprit, could you please try following once.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z\-]+)\/([0-9]+)$ ficha_jugador.php?idjugador=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

I have added a condition there to rewrite to index.html if and only if Uri has non existing directory/file, why because it will create an infinite loop without a condition, since you are rewriting everything to index.html and everything(by regex) matched index.html also, hence loop and 500 internal error you are getting.

Also your rule to rewrite from `http://localhost:80/alvaro-garcia-canto/alvaro-garcia/1304` TO `http://localhost:80/ficha_jugador.php?idjugador=1304` have been changed into a single line above.

***NOTE:*** To fix this either make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: @user2954295, You need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path . forexample if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this either make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: this is just fantastic! you guys rule!!! Thanks a lot!!!